# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code (for example)

```
 CREATE TABLE s(
    id int,
    y int NOT NULL UNQIUE,
    x int NOT NULL,
    z varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    k varchar(50),
    l varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    m int NOT NULL,
    v int NOT NULL,
    c int NOT NULL,
    r varchar(400),
    CONSTRAINT s_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

But i get ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis. What I made wrong?

Comment: is it the exact code that you are using?, if so, you are using `UNQIUE` instead of `UNIQUE`

Comment: Spelling error UNIQUE, column y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE s(
    id int,
    y int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    x int NOT NULL,
    z varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    k varchar(50),
    l varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    m int NOT NULL,
    v int NOT NULL,
    c int NOT NULL,
    r varchar(400),
    CONSTRAINT s_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: How does this differ from @jarlh and Lamak's earlier comments?

Comment: It does not, because oviously there is one solution.